# Unable to record the script using JMeter 4.0 & 5.0.

Tags: jmeter-4.0

WHen I am creating the script using Jmeter It's throwing below error.

The same script I have created 1 month back using Jmeter4.0. Today I observed the below error message.

Can you please help me.
[image]

Comment: close jmeter GUI. Try reopening and loading the same file.

Comment: I tried, but still, same error message getting. previous working scripts also not working and not able to create the new script also.

Comment: Change your HTTP Request samplers to HttpClient4

Answer (score 0):

It may be connected to [invalid certificate](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/26/jmeter-recording/), as OctoPerf tutorial suggests:

> Stop JMeter,
>
> Change the jmeter.properties,
>
> Delete any existing  / bin / ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt,
>
> And restart JMeter

Also you can extend certificate expiration:

> By default, JMeter generates a Root CA valid only 7 days. That’s annoying since we need to redo the procedures below every week. But, there is a way to hack this.
>
> Open /bin/jmeter.properties and locate the following lines:
>
> ```
> #The default validity for certificates created by JMeter
> #proxy.cert.validity=7
> ```

Comment: We have some scripts, Those scripts successfully ran 1 week back, today when I run the script it's not working. Same issues I observed below error . can you please help me.ava.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)